# How to bring together multiple js files

Tags: jquery

As shown above, several js files are being imported into index.html.
I'd like to bring these files together, but I'm wondering how to do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugin/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugin/backbone/backbone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugin/tui-code-snippet/dist/tui-code-snippet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugin/tui-pagination/dist/tui-pagination.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugin/tui-date-picker/dist/tui-date-picker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugin/raphael/raphael.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="common/chart/dist/tui-chart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="common/chart/dist/maps/world.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript" src="common/grid/data/basic-dummy.js"></script>
```

Comment: You could use Gulp to achieve this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat

Comment: If you're using ASP.Net MVC you could use [Bundling and Minification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification).

Comment: What can I do without using gulp?